# Replace leading zeros with spaces

Tags: c#, python, regex, powershell, notepad++

I have a text file of multiple records. Each record has a field which has some number of leading zeros that I need to replace with that number of spaces. A record will look like this:

```
A206   000001204   X4609
```

I need the record to look like this:

```
A206        1204   X4609
```

I'm extremely unfamiliar with regex but the following regex seems to find the matches that I need:

```
\b0+
```

However, I have no idea how to do the replacement. A ReplaceAll for Notepad++ would be awesome but I can also create a quick program in C#, Powershell, or Python if needed. Can anyone give me some pointers on the regex for this?

Comment: What pointers? What do you need? You seem to have the regex, right?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why go to the trouble of reformatting your file in the first place?

Comment: Not all text files can be parsed with regex or they can get very messy.  I've been parsing text files for over 40 years.  Without seeing a sample of the text file I cannot give a great solution.

Comment: @nicael - I'm having problems with the replacement. I can't seem to figure out how to replace x number of zeros with x number of spaces.

Comment: @BobKaufman - the system that generates the file can't generate it any other way and the system that will be accepting the file needs it without the leading zeros on that field. So I need to reformat the file.

Comment: Why the downvotes on my question? What did I do wrong and how can I do better next time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `\b0+` would probably work.

Here using the [`Regex.Replace()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) in `C#`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\b0+", m => "".PadLeft(m.Value.Length,' '));
```

The last argument to `Replace()` is a simple lambda function that returns a string of the same length as the number of matched `0`s, but consisting only of spaces

---

You can do the same in `PowerShell`, substituting a `scriptblock` for the lambda function:

```
PS C:\> $inputString = 'A206   000001204   X4609'
PS C:\> [regex]::Replace($inputString, '\b0+', {param($m) ' ' * $m.Value.Length})
A206        1204   X4609
```

Comment: Where are the spaces?

Comment: So I went with the C# solution but it only replaces x number of zeros with 1 space. I need to replace x number of zeros with x number of spaces.

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen a lambda delegate in PowerShell.

Comment: @BaconBits PowerShell has no syntax for lambdas (hence, the use of a scriptblock)

Answer (score 2):

Does this suffice?

```
while (dataString.Contains(" 0")) // while data contains a zero after a space
    dataString = dataString.Replace(" 0", "  "); // Replace with two spaces
```

Though this doesn't use regex.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Replace with `"  "` (two spaces) to preserve the leading space as well

Comment: @MasterXD Your edited solution works as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using Npp:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b0`
- Replace with:  (a space)
- <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Mathias'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674521/1630171) lambda expression solution you could also use a more "conventional" approach like this:

```
$str = 'A206   000001204   X4609'
$re  = '\b0+'

if ($str -match $re) {
  $str -replace $re, (' ' * $matches[0].Length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Notepad++ regex suggestion is not as short as Toto's, but it is a little more strict.

Find what: `(?: \K|\G)0`

Replace with:

This will seek out a space, then forget it (compliments of `\K` -- the Keep metacharacter), then individually match each consecutive zero (compliments of `\G` -- the Continue metacharacter).

Replace All will deliver the desired result.

I am posting this to make this page a little more accommodating for future researchers who may have slightly different requirements.